# SharePoint 2013 SAML Claims Encoding

Tags: sharepoint-server, saml

We have implemented Custom SAML identity provider which is providing SAML claim in below foramt "i:0e.t|SAML|domain\user" while window authentication is accepting in "i:0#.w|domain\user" format,which leads to two parallel identity for same user.Please note we are pulling user data from same LDAP for both identity provider.How can we encode this identity either at SAML identity provider(Other than ADFS) or SharePoint side?
Any pointer will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's supposed to work by design. If you need Windows authentication to be in same format as ADFS, you need to add your Windows Identity provider in ADFS.

Comment: I am aware of this but looking for a custom solution so that we can handle the claim based token and get users authorized using windows account .